# how to check if period sign(.) is removed from the word in textbox and disable drop down optoin in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want disable "Gram" option in the drop down if the period sign "." is only one. Example: 5.50 //disable Gram if period sign . is two disable "Kilogram" Example: 5.5.5 // disable kilogram

I had successfully disable gram if sign. is only one.

```
$('#qts').on('keypress input change', function() {
    var value = $('#unit').children('[value="1"]');
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') > -1) {
        value.attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        value.attr('disabled', false);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Check to see if it contains a `.` using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) then disable it if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex match like following :

```
var m = '120.500.66';
var k = m.match(/\.+/ig);
console.log(k.length) // this will return 2
```

In your case :

```
$('#qts').on('keypress input change', function() {

   var value = $('#unit').children('[value="1"]');
   var dotLength = $(this).val().match(/\.+/ig);

   // if . more than one
   if ( dotLength > 1 ) {
     value.attr('disabled', true);
   } else {
     value.attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Simple [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/rn0ex09j/)